# What are the 2 moving pieces hinged on a toilet bowl called?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

What are the 2 moving pieces hinged on a toilet bowl called?

Is the one that has no hole called "a lid" and the one with a hole called "a cover"?

There are 2 toilets in my house, one  for women and one for men.

The cover of the woman one is always on the bowl and women don't have to do nothing just sit on it.

The cover of the man one is always not on the bowl and men don't have to lift it up when peeing.

Sometimes the one for women got occupied, then my daughter has to use the one for men. I often say "*make sure you put the cover down on the toilet bowl before sitting on it*"

**Is it correct to say that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the one with a hole is a *seat*, not *cover*.

The part names are [shown](https://www.homestratosphere.com/parts-of-toilet/) in the first diagram on the left.

As for the other part, we can call it *seat cover*, as shown in the diagram, or *lid*; we need not worry too much.  What we need to differentiate are *seat* and *seat cover* (or *lid*) as only the former is meant to be sat on.

> Make sure you put the *seat* down on the toilet bowl before sitting on it.

Comment: Wikipedia said "Toilet seat"  is a hinged unit consisting of a round or oval open seat, and usually a lid. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilet_seat